# VBA Array getting -1.#IND value if the macro isn't paused

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

This code takes in a chart and the last data point, then sorts the data points .top for all the series and adds 12.5 (size of the data labels) to make sure they are not overlapping.
The problem is if I donot have the wait call to pause the macro, the lines

`dLabels(i, 1) = .SeriesCollection(i).Points(lastpoint).DataLabel.Top
 dLabels(i, 2) = i`

Will give me a value of `-1.#IND`, but if I Step through it or "pause" the macro everything is fine.
`oSh` is a `Shape` and `lastpoint` is a `Long`.
Is the macro just working too fast to get a value from the label?

```
Sub MoveLabels(oSH, lastpoint)
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dLabels() As Double
*Call Wait(3)*    ' just pauses the macro for less than a second
If oSH.Name = "SCG_US" Then 
    With oSH.Chart
            ' the -2 will only allow it to move the labels that are not static (the last two in the series)
        ReDim dLabels(1 To .SeriesCollection.Count - 2, 2)
        For i = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count - 2
             **dLabels(i, 1) = .SeriesCollection(i).Points(lastpoint).DataLabel.Top**
             dLabels(i, 2) = i
             'dLabels(i, 3) = .Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Values(lastpoint)dLabels(2, 1)
        Next
            Call BubbleSort(dLabels) 'simple sort of array
       ' This section sets top values for all data labelsto be at least 12.5 units apart
        For j = 2 To .SeriesCollection.Count - 2
            **If dLabels(j - 1, 1) + 12.5 > dLabels(j, 1) Then**
                dLabels(j, 1) = dLabels(j, 1) + (12.5 - (dLabels(j, 1) - dLabels(j - 1, 1)))
            End If
        Next j


Sub Wait(waitTime)
    Start = Timer
    While Timer < Start + waitTime
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Here is the call statements that I changed the order they were in:

```
If .SeriesCollection.Count > 1 Then Call MoveLabels(oSH, 1) 'moves first label
If .SeriesCollection.Count > 1 And lastpoint <> 999 Then Call MoveLabels(oSH, lastpoint) ' moves last label
```

Comment: please post the code that is in the `Wait()` sub

Comment: The wait should have nothing to do with this, but sure.

Comment: So I was sending in lastpoint = the number of the last data points in the series, first, then sending in lastpoint = 1 for the first points in the series.  When I switched the order I was calling the sub routine the problem was solved.  I also change dLabels back to a long, but that didn't really change anything.    I am baffled about why this didn't work and now does work.

Comment: you are right, the `wait` sub has nothing to do with it. just wanted to make sure that there was nothing in it that may have caused the issue

Comment: what does "sending in" mean? .... what do you mean "switched the order" ? how did you switch?

Comment: can you post the updated code below the original code? (or in an answer)

Comment: Sending in , means the parameters that are being sent with the call statement.

Comment: I think the error may have come when there isn't a data label in the first or last point.